# Scroll to get the answer of a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

On the Stack Exchange Android app, I have to click on the "answer" button to get the answers of a question. It confuses me, because I try to scroll to see the answers, but it doesn't work.

It would be nice if the answers would load when the user scrolls below a certain point.

Comment: This would be quite the UI change from where things stand now. But I've wondered if it would be better to have the app UI mimic the desktop/mobile site UI.

Comment: Though I personally like the way the UI is currently setup on the app, I do continually find myself trying to scroll down. Old habits die hard?

Comment: It is a little bit to get used to when you are familiar with the (Mobile) Web interface, but I dunno; I kinda like it myself.

Comment: How about just a big button at the bottom of the question that says "View [] Answers" and acts as the tab being pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are going to add this button for a test run in version 0.1.42 coming out later tonight. I might end up removing it if it brings up more issues than it solves, but right now tapping that button is the exact same as tapping the "1 ANSWER" button on the top or sliding to the right.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like a compromise. For me, I know to swipe left and right since I've been using the app since day one. Is there a way to do A/B testing or ask the newest group of testers for their feedback to see if the feature matters?

Comment: There are ways to do that, yeah. And since we use Google Analytics in the app already I could set up events for the button clicks... but I think I'll just ask our designer for his opinion tomorrow :)

Comment: *No.* No. **No**. Swipe left/right was pretty clear. The extra button is unnecessary and (triply?) redundant.